# How to create an image file with fixed size in Android?

Tags: java, android

I built a simple app that you can pick a photo of yourself, select a border for it and then save it as image. The way I did this is adding 2 ImageViews on top of each other in a parent view. Then converting this parent view to image and save. However with this way, the resulting image size depends on the device screen size. If the device screen is small, a small final image is generated.

What I want is creating an image file with a size of 500x800 pixels at all times regardless of device. What is the correct way to do this?

The preview on the screen could be small, but when I click save button I need it to be exactly 500x800.

Answer (score 0):

First, convert your image to bitmap by :

```
Bitmap bitmapImage= BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.large_icon);
```

Or, if you have Uri of image then use this to convert it to bitmap:

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imageUri.getPath());
```

Both of this will give you a bitmap of your image.

Now to resize your image  use this code:

```
Bitmap scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, imageWidth, imageHeight, true);
```

Then convert it into File.

Answer (score 0):

To Add to Jason Answer, we found the best way to scale the image, is to use this to scale it up or down.

```
public Bitmap scaleCenterCrop(Bitmap source, int newHeight, int newWidth) {
    int sourceWidth = source.getWidth();
    int sourceHeight = source.getHeight();
    // Compute the scaling factors to fit the new height and width, respectively.
    // To cover the final image, the final scaling will be the bigger
    // of these two.
    float xScale = (float) newWidth / sourceWidth;
    float yScale = (float) newHeight / sourceHeight;
    float scale = Math.max(xScale, yScale);
    // Now get the size of the source bitmap when scaled
    float scaledWidth = scale * sourceWidth;
    float scaledHeight = scale * sourceHeight;
    // Let's find out the upper left coordinates if the scaled bitmap
    // should be centered in the new size give by the parameters
    float left = (newWidth - scaledWidth) / 2;
    float top = (newHeight - scaledHeight) / 2;
    // The target rectangle for the new, scaled version of the source bitmap will now
    // be
    RectF targetRect = new RectF(left, top, left + scaledWidth, top + scaledHeight);
    // Finally, we create a new bitmap of the specified size and draw our new,
    // scaled bitmap onto it.
    Bitmap dest = Bitmap.createBitmap(newWidth, newHeight, source.getConfig());
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(dest);
    canvas.drawBitmap(source, null, targetRect, null);
    return dest;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try to below code to save **bitmap image as custom height & width**, Below is a snippet of code that will allow you to **resize a Bitmap**.

```
public Bitmap getResizeBitmap(Bitmap bmp, int newHeight, int newWidth) {

int width = bmp.getWidth();
int height = bmp.getHeight();

float scaleWidth = ((float) newWidth) / width;
float scaleHeight = ((float) newHeight) / height;

// CREATE A MATRIX FOR THE MANIPULATION
 Matrix matrix = new Matrix();

// RESIZE THE BIT MAP
 matrix.postScale(scaleWidth, scaleHeight);

// RECREATE THE NEW BITMAP
Bitmap resizeBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp, 0, 0, width, height, matrix, false);

return resizeBitmap;
}
```